# Android Images in Email using Intent

Tags: android, image, email, android-intent

I have a webview that displays the html content fetched from the server. It works fine. But If I try to use intent to sent this content via email to someone. Rest of the html is displayed correctly in the email client but image are not displayed instead "obj" in a box is shown.

And when received the same email, still the "obj" in a box is there for images. I can now open the images via clicking on the "obj".

Is it possible to display the images in email.

Images are part of html, not added from device.

I have searched but non other solution seems to solve my problem.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/html");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, this.news.getNewsTitle());
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(this.htmlContentDetails));

                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Sending mail..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email clients installed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```